# Android Navigation Drawer with progress bar on item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-progressbar

I don't know how to implement progress bar to navigation drawer item. I would like to run some asynchronous task for downloads. During download should be shown progress bar into line with some item. After download completed, I would like to hide progress bar on navigation drawer. 
I have custom drawer adapter with data model, but I don't know how to hide right progress bar for right item.
Sample will be best cure for me.
Thank you for your help,

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawerTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/drawerHeaderProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/drawerHeaderCheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="#DADADC" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Rado.

Comment: Just add a progressbar  in your drawer in the xml

Comment: I have it. The problem is how to hide it after some time after when async tasks finish.

Comment: Post the XML containing it.

Comment: I added to main post.

Comment: In the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` if you get what you wanted, simply set the visibility of this progressbar to gone. eg: `mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. That should do it.

Comment: ASync task is running in main activity. In that activity I have only ListView as drawerList with CustomDrawerAdapter. I am searching how to get "into" this adapter and hide progressbar in one of its items.

Comment: Does anything changes in the drawer after the asynctask? Like any value comes or anything?

Comment: no. The only change will be that progress bar next to one item will be turn off.

Comment: Then in onPostExecute you can call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter. And in the adapter class you can use a condition using a boolean in order to stop it.

Comment: It's sounds good, I will try notifyDataSetChanged. Thank you.